# Docker for Mac and VPN can't connect inside container

Tags: macos, docker, vpn

I am running into a block and can't seem to find the answer. I have Docker for Mac on OSX. I can build and run the containers fine. One of my containers runs a sails app that utilizes sequelize to connect to a SQL database. The database is behind the corporate VPN. I am connected to the VPN through openconnect. Outside of the container (on the host), I can run the application just fine and it connects. Inside of the container, I cannot access the VPN and get a bad connection error. I have tried restarting Docker after the VPN is connected but still cannot connect. I don't see any settings in the GUI for VPN or network handling, other than proxies. I have tried with --network="bridge" and --network="host"

This is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581518/hitting-resources-in-a-private-network-from-within-a-docker-container-using-vpn)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the VPN, because maybe in the vpn it's enabled only determinate IP, you need to nat all request from docker with your private ip of your vpn, try to install the vpn on virtualbox.